# Output sequences for multivariable output for LSTM in Keras

Tags: keras, output, lstm

Please help to understand how to form output sequence for LSTM network in Keras.
For example I have data

```
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]
 [5]]
```

I can for input sequences as per [samples, timesteps, features] tensor 
- assume 3 input sequence and 2 output. So

```
Input seq      Output seq
[[[1,2,3]]] -> [[4, 5]]
```

but what about multivariable input and output?!
Neural network may be several neurons - one neuron for each feature
Example (two features data, two features input and two features output):

Data:

```
[[1, 10]
 [2, 20]
 [3, 30]
 [4, 40]
 [5, 50]]
```

Input tensor (samples, timesteps - 3, features - 2)

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]]]
```

But output matrix for Y

```
[[4, 5, 30, 40]]
```

- but it doesn't sense we have a mess with completely 
  different features!!!

Can I conclude that in case of Keras we can form output sequences for only
one feature?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

For multivariate also it would be similar, if your data has 2 features as you have mentioned in your question:

```
[[1, 10]
 [2, 20]
 [3, 30]
 [4, 40]
 [5, 50]]
```

And you want to prepare it with`Input tensor (samples, timesteps - 3, features - 2)` ,ie 3 timestep and each record has 2 variables then it would look like below:

```
 x=[
      [[1,10],[2,20],[3,30]],
      [[2,20],[3,30],[4,40]],
      [[3,30],[4,40],[5,50]]       
  ]
y=[[4, 5],[5,6],[6,7]]
```

I just assumed you had value 6 and 7 otherwise according to your given data you can only have just one(1) record in x ie (1 sample,3 timestep,2featues)

```
 x=[
          [[1,10],[2,20],[3,30]]
   ]
```

and just one record of y

```
y=[[4, 5]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer  - are you sure (assuming we have only 1 to 5 data for simplicity) that X tensor will be x=[
      [[1,10],[2,20],[3,30]],
      [[2,20],[3,30],[4,40]],
      [[3,30],[4,40],[5,50]]       
  ] but not [[[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]]]? It is very critical

Comment: Yes,,x will be ....x=[ [[1,10],[2,20],[3,30]]]  and y will be y=[[4, 5]]....with just 5 values you can only have 1 sample ...because 123 will give 45 next there there cannot be any more sample as next 3 input will be 234 and output is 56..But you dont have 6.I hope you got it